# WPF (XBAP) vs ASP.NET MVC on Intranet?

Tags: .net, wpf, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, xbap

I need to make an application that will be used within an organization. They need it to be available on their network. I have considered two options ASP.NET MVC and WPF (web).

WPF Web Browser applications can be accessed on IE and Firefox.

What are the pros and cons of using ASP.NET MVC and WPF over the Intranet ?

Should I go with ASP.NET MVC or WPF ?

Answer (score 0):

If your going to build a web app, go with MVC. If you dont need any of the extra stuff that WPF would provide you there is no reason to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Application used within an organization on their network.
Why are you limiting this to a browser application?

If you don't want to deploy an application then ASP.NET MVC.

If you need features of WPF the use it directly (not as an XBAP).

Comment: PCs on the network need not install a client app, so exposing through browser using MVC or WPF Browser application...

Comment: Then update the question to  "I need to make an browser application"   and "WPF XBAP" and tag it XBAP

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of application you intend to build. With WPF you have more possibilities for design and usage of local ressources. However if you run the application within the browser you still have some restrictions. For WPF you need to have .NET installed on the clients in the correct version.

If you just want to display data without heavy graphic interaction I would build an ASP.NET MVC application. It's platform independent and easy to upgrade. You might have to consider mobile devices (smart phones, pads, ...) as well. Your browser application will run there as well.

Another question is, which technology you know better. Both WPF and ASP.NET need some time to learn properly, so that you can create a performant and easy maintainable application.

**pros and cons**

ASP.NET MVC

- plattform independant, no framework required
- runs on every browser, even mobile devices

WPF

- nicer and more performant user interface
- usage of local ressources possible
- possiblity of multi threading and asynchronous programming

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the requirements of your application, it's hard to say. Both have benefits.

If you have an existing team, I would look at their skill set. Developing for desktop with WPF or for the browser using HTML/JS/CSS/MVC are both very different beasts and require different skills and experience.

Also, I tried WPF in the browser (known as XBAP) on a project a few years ago and found that it wasn't all that great in practice.

Answer (score 0):

WPF in web? Ma ybe Silverlight.

Silverlight pros:

- more rapid development in compare to ASP.NET MVC
- good suitable for enterprise intranet
  contras:
- need to have Silverlight add-in installed.

ASP.NET MVC pros:
- no need to install any add-in or something else
- very easy to consume from different platforms (Mac, Linux, Windows, there are some differences in Silverlight for different platforms and with Linux could be Problems)

For enterprise intranet I will select Silverlight for project, but technology Silverlight or ASP.NET MVC is depending from project requirements.